# Disabling sounds in KDE app (without KDE installed)

Tags: debian, kde-4

I have an old-school X setup in Debian, mostly running WindowMaker with some Gnome applications. I have just installed the K3B cd burning package, which has pulled in some KDE infrastructure packages.

Burning CDs works fine, but every time it does something it makes a variety of incredibly stupid noises to let me know it's done it. How do I turn these off?

The standard instructions involve running systemsettings and changing a setting. Unfortunately, after installing and running systemsettings, all it does is tell me that it can't find any views to display and exits (and makes a stupid noise while doing so). This is presumably because I don't have a full KDE installation.

Help. I need to burn some CDs. If I have to put up with this for much longer I won't be responsible for my actions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how to disable notifications in K3b:

- Go to *Settings* → *Configure K3b...*
- Select *Notifications*
- Click on every list item and uncheck *Play a sound*

This works for most KDE applications, but usually they have a separate menu entry:
*Settings* → *Configure notifications...*

Comment: Thank-you, that works. Although I still don't know why in the gods' names the default is to have the sounds *enabled*.